# MySQL: Why is NULL ignored in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database

I have a table with the following possible values for the column field_value.

But when I try to select all values which are not 'CB', the query result also ignores all NULL values.

Why does this happen?

```
mysql> select distinct field_value from TableName;
+--------------+
| field_value  |
+--------------+
| S            |
| NULL         |
| CA           |
| CB           |
+--------------+
4 rows in set (6.32 sec)

mysql> select distinct field_value from TableName where field_value!='CB';
+--------------+
| field_value  |
+--------------+
| S            |
| CA           |
+--------------+
2 rows in set (0.15 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: you can not compare a field value to NULL with comparison operator , instead you have to use IS NULL operator.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysql+null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because any comparisons with `NULL` also yield `NULL` (i.e. not truthy nor falsy).

The special operators `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL` are used to make useful comparisons against `NULL`.

Your query should therefore be:

```
... WHERE field_value!='CB' OR field_value IS NULL;
```

See also: [Working with NULL values](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html)

Answer (score 2):

Because `NULL` is unknown and `unknown` doesn't mean that is it not equal to `CB`.

if you want to return null values add a condition (*IS NULL*) in your query,

```
SELECT ...
FROM   ...
where field_value != 'CB' OR field_value IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

NULL is not equal to any value.  NULL is not unequal to any value.  NULL is not even equal to NULL.  Try it if you don't believe it.

```
select * from anytable
where NULL = NULL
or not NULL = NULL
or NULL != NULL
or not NULL != NULL
```

You should get zero rows retrieved.  The result of all four conditions is UNKNOWN.    *unknown* is not the same thing as TRUE.  *unknown* is not the same thing as FALSE.  If this sounds like a mess to you, then you are probably starting to understand.

It's best to avoid using nullable columns in WHERE conditions,  unless you are prepared to think things through very carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Actually NULL means “a missing unknown value”

[Check this page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html)