# NOT IN clause and NULL value

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

The NOT IN clause is omitting the ***NULL*** values when checking the condition.

```
INPUT  
ID  NAME  
1   A  
2   <null>
3   C

SELECT... FROM...
WHERE NAME NOT IN ('C')
```

is only returning ID value 1. I need both 1 & 2.

Could this be done?

Comment: just add an `OR name is null` it the end of the line

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12966873/mysql-why-is-null-ignored-in-mysql

Comment: Basically you want to show table data except where name is C...??

Comment: See this [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17442229/where-clause-rejecting-rows-if-null-occurred)

Comment: What is your NAME TYPE..??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
WHERE NAME NOT IN ('C') OR NAME IS NULL
```

Answer (score 3):

Either you check NULL values

```
select *
from not_in
where name not in ('C') or name is null;
```

or you can convert NULL values in any other character with coalesce. I use ' ' in the sample below.

```
select *
from not_in
where coalesce(name, ' ') not in ('C');
```

Answer (score 2):

Correct SQL would be

```
SELECT... FROM...
WHERE NAME NOT IN ('C')
or NAME is NULL
```

That's because any comparisons with `NULL` also yield `NULL` (i.e. not truthy nor falsy). (Credit to @Jack)

Refer:
 [MySQL: Why is NULL ignored in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12966873/mysql-why-is-null-ignored-in-mysql)
[Working of Null Values](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html)

Comment: @asifsid88 - The reason is correct but your condition is wrong. It should be `Name IS NULL` IMO.

Comment: @asifsid88 - Glad. +1 for the given reason now.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT... 
FROM...
WHERE NAME NOT IN ('C') 
    OR NAME IS NULL

SELECT... 
FROM...
WHERE ISNULL(NAME, '') NOT IN ('C')
```

Comment: `ISNULL(NAME, '') NOT IN ('C') ` will never be optimized. Should be never assumed as a solution.

Comment: agreed - using any function on a column invalidates the index; this is why I cringe when I see code like "WHERE lower(username) = :param" then I'm asked why this query is so slow "there's an index on username!"

Comment: @zerkms - although `NAME NOT IN ('C') OR NAME IS NULL` will probably result in a full table scan, at least on Oracle.

Comment: @APC: `NOT IN` would for any B-Tree based indexes. For oracle - depending on the index type. If you have bitmap there is a chance it won't.